# "The associated script cannot be loaded" Error Unity. C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with this error (mentioned below). I’m not able to set the Game manager thing on the hierarchy to the EndGame Trigger due to this problem.

That's the error. Here's the code.
EndTrigger

````
```



 using UnityEngine;

        public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
        {

            public GameManager gameManager;

            void OnTriggerEnter()
            {
                gameManager.CompleteLevel();
            }

        }
````

```
Game Manager
**

    public void CompleteLevel()
    {
        Debug.Log("Complete");
    }

**
```

Comment: Do you have any compiler errors? Are your script files named exactly the same way as the class (+ `.cs`)? So you should have one file named `NewBehaviourScript` and one file named `GameManager` in the Assets view

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
```

change to

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
```

Then just make sure your game manager is assigned either in inspector or via code.

Comment: Im still having the error with that edit. Got any other ideas?